# Minidump on exit in QGIS (2.8.2- Wien) 64-bit version when using GDAL in plugin

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, qgis-plugins

I am working on a plugin for QGIS that is working fine on 32-bit versions but I am having some problems while using it on the 64-bit standalone installation package. 
I have tried on several machines and on all of them QGIS locks up and creates a minidump on exit when certain parts of the code in the plugin has been ran. The plugin still works, the only problem seems to be the crash dump on exit.

As far as I have been able to tell this line of code using the gdal-module seems to be causing the crash dumps:

```
    gdal_dsm = gdal.Open(filepath_dsm)
    dsm = gdal_dsm.ReadAsArray().astype(numpy.float) - this line of code is the offending one.
    ...
    gdal_dsm = None
    dsm = None
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it a problem with the 64-bit standalone installation of QGIS? Is there anyway to avoid the crash dump on exit for potential users of the plugin that might be using this installation package?

Comment: I believe this is the issue https://hub.qgis.org/issues/10756 on windows7 64bit the minidump appears when closing qgis each time in my experience